# Chrome Extensiones - Pulsar botón para cargar vídeo no funciona repetidas veces

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extensión-google-chrome

Estoy desarrollando una App para **google chrome extensiones**. Tengo una función que cada vez que se presione un botón debe cargar un vídeo.

Sucede que al presionar la primera vez el botón, la  función  se llama  perfectamente, pero si vuelvo a presionarlo, no ocurre nada, o desconozco lo que ocurre. La función debe cargar un vídeo cada vez que se presiona el botón, pero solo funciona la primera vez.

**El código**

```
  document.getElementById('audio1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var mediaElement1 = document.getElementById("ad1"); 
  mediaElement1.src = "video1.mp4";
  cargar_audio1(); 
  });
```

**La función**

```
   var analyser;
   function cargar_audio1() {

   var audio1 = document.getElementById('ad1');
   var audioContext = new AudioContext();
   analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
   analyser.minDecibels = -60;
   analyser.maxDecibels = -10;  
   analyser.fftSize = 32;
   var source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio1);
   source.connect(analyser);
   analyser.connect(audioContext.destination); 
   audio1.play();
   visualizar_datos_audio();    
  }
```

Adjunto también la captura de pantalla del error que arroja cuando presiono por segunda vez el botón [image: Captura de pantalla del error]

Answer (score 2):

Parece que para poder crearlo de nuevo, nececesitarías obligatoriamente destruir el nodo que has creado en primer lugar:

```
   var source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio1);
```

Como puedes ver, el error dice claramente que "createMediaElementSource" HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode. Parece que con crearlo una vez y reconectarlo al nuevo medio que deseas reproducir, es suficiente.

Por tanto:

```
var source;
if (source == undefined) {
  //Esto hace que sólo se cree si no lo has definido previamente 
  source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio1);
}
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

Adjunto el [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460984/problems-disconnecting-nodes-with-audiocontext-web-audio-api) de donde encontré la información

Comment: gracias voy a intentar lo que me sugieres, por el momento tuve que solucionarlo de una forma poco ortodoxa usando iframes que recarguen la pagina XD

Comment: a veces elegir mal camino complica mucho!!! ;) siempre busca opciones antes de complicarte!